# Calibration / Tuning Tool Support

Tags: ros, ros2, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've some years of experience in running ROS1 applications and tuning a limited number of scalar and vector parameters by means of `rosparam`.

For future tasks I'd like to move an existing larger scale embedded application to ROS. As this application has a high number of parameters, I'm interested in more convenient (graphical) tools for tuning the ROS node.

Could you please give me a hint on that? This questions refers to ros1 and ros2.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404356/calibration-/-tuning-tool-support/) by [holunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/64636/holunder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2022-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The canonical answer to this would likely be: [rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure) (which also [exists for ROS 2](https://index.ros.org/p/rqt_reconfigure/)):

[rqt_reconfigure example http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=reconfigure_gui2.png](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=reconfigure_gui2.png)

Whether that would fit your requirements only you can decide of course.

Your post confuses me somewhat though:

> I've some years of experience in running ROS1 applications and tuning a limited number of scalar and vector parameters by means of `rosparam`.

did you have to restart the node(s) for which you changed those parameters? Nodes re-reading their ROS parameters at runtime is a known anti-pattern, but that would be the only way to "tune" parameters while things are running.

[dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) would be the infrastructure to use for runtime updating of parameters, but if you were already using that, I'd expect `rqt_reconfigure` to be a known tool.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [holunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/64636/holunder/) on 2022-08-01**:
Thanks, That's looking exactly as the one I was searching for. I'll investigate this further.

I didn't restart nodes during parameter tuning.  It was relasted to controller tuning or enabling / disabling specific functions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-08-02**:\

> I didn't restart nodes during parameter tuning.

sounds like those nodes implemented the anti-pattern then.